# How can I get my device ID for AdMob Ads?

Tags: admob

I went through the steps found [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/test-ads), but it doesn't log out my device ID like it should. I have a Galaxy S9 Plus. I also tried using my advertising ID found in Google settings, but that didn't work either. How can I get my Device ID?